# in_addr_t to string

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have an IP address stored in `in_addr_t` and I want to create the corresponding string representation of this data type (e.g. `in_addr_t` to `10.0.0.1`).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`inet_ntop()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html) - convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from binary to text form.

Comment: inet_ntop takes const void *restrict src as argument. My type is in_addr_t. How can I convert between the two of them?

Comment: @cateof: You can simply pass the address of your `in_addr_t` variable as the `src` argument, with `AF_INET` as the `af` argument.

Comment: More recent documentation [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString*)long2ip:(uint32_t)ip
{
    char str[40];
    struct in_addr myaddr;
    myaddr.s_addr = htonl(ip);
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &myaddr, str, sizeof(str)))
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",str];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`char *inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in);`
 is the desired function.

Comment: inet_ntoa() seems to be considered deprecated.

Comment: inet_ntoa takes an in_addr that is not the same as inet_addr_t. Please consider changing your answer.

Comment: `inet_ntoa` is a non-reentrant functions, because it returns static buffer. So better to use `inet_ntop` instead of `inet_ntoa`.