# what are addresses of type in_addr_t inet_ntoa etc

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, in-addr

Ok before posting this question I have checked threads here
[in_addr_t to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768183/in-addr-t-to-string)

my question is different.

I understand that inet_ntoa function is of following type

```
char * inet_ntoa (struct in_addr in);
```

What I want to know is what is `in_addr_t`

what will be the representation when it is used in a socket program.

I checked the structure definition in `<netinet/in.h>`

```
   typedef uint32_t in_addr_t;

   struct in_addr {
       in_addr_t s_addr;
   };
```

is of above type. I do not want to print in_addr_t to char * as inet_ntoa does.
I want to see what is in_addr_t.So how can it be done or what exactly is in_addr_t and why is it used again and again in socket programming.
If I am not mistaken it is defined as

typedef uint32_t in_addr_t;

So if `in_addr_t` is `unsigned 32 bit` int I want to see what is that and not the `char *` which prints 192.168.1.1 kind of output on stdout.

Comment: Based on the questions you've been asking I recommend you pick up a book like the classic *Internetworking with TCP/IP* by Comer.

Answer (score 18):

As we all know (we do, right?) an `IPv4` address is represented using an unsigned 32 bits integer. Us puny humans aren't so good with large numbers (or small ones) so we use dot decimal notation. (Did you know you're at `1076000524` right now ? Neither did I).

However, since you dug through `netinet` and found out what is clearly specified by **[the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html)**

> The `<netinet/in.h>` header shall define
>   the `in_addr` structure, which shall
>   include at least the following member:
>
> `in_addr_t  s_addr`

Which is

> `in_addr_t`
>       Equivalent to the type `uint32_t` as described in `<inttypes.h>`

you can print it.

```
printf("My unreadable addres is %u\n", in.s_addr);
```

**Quick, what does `134744072` stand for ?**

Comment: You didn't specify the most important thing - byte order. Everything else is obvious.

Comment: @Simon Can you expand on that ?

Comment: @cnicutar Network byte order is big-endian. You must use use functions like `htons`/`htonl` ("host to network, short/long") or `ntohs`/`ntohl` ("network to host, short/long") to get the correct values regardless of the architecture.

Comment: btw, result for `134744072` is the same regardless of the endianess :)

Answer (score 0):

You must translate 134744072 in hex using:

```
printf("My unreadable address is %lX\n", in.s_addr);
```

Use `%lX` for long unsigned hexadecimal.
This address is: `8.8.8.8`